# PXE-E77 Bad or Missing Discovery Server list

Tags: virtualbox, pxe, kickstart

I am trying to use kickstart file to automate the installation of the CentOS7 server in my home lab. I have configured HTTP, Xinetd, and dnsmasq but I am still get the PXE-E77 error. I am using bridged Adapter Networking in the VM.

Here is my dnsmasq configuration

```
interface=enp0s3,lo
domain=clusterdhcp-range=enp0s3,192.168.43.35,192.168.43.53,255.255.255.0,2h
log-dhcp
dhcp-range=192.168.43.0,proxy
dhcp-option=3,192.168.43.1
dhcp-option=28,192.168.43.255
dhcp-option=42,0.0.0.0
pxe-prompt="Press F8 for Menu",60
pxe-service=x86PC, "Automate installation with kickstart"
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/var/lib/tftpboot
```

I tried using a proxy, still not working. The error is
[image: Virtual Box image]